# How does a person use the word behooves in a sentence correctly?

Tags: word-usage

Word is behooves how to use the word behooves in a sentence correctly

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Please check a dictionary first. If you still don't understand what the word means or its usage, please edit your question and tell us why your question can't be answered with a dictionary.

Comment: It behooves you to do some research, as Eddie Kal says.